PHP laravel create new session
I am developing an API to manage active sessions in my Laravel application and would like to know if it is possible to create a session for a user.
I have the following code below, but it does not behave in the same way as a session created when accessing the system. It does not even create a session file in the "storage/framework/sessions" directory. Is there any way to create this "fake" session?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                session_start();

                foreach ($params['inputedData'] as $key=> $value) {
                    session([$key=> $value]);
                }

                $retorno["created_sessions"][$params['inputedData']->$nameUserSession] = ($params['inputedData']);
                $retorno['metadados']["status"]  = 200;
                $retorno['metadados']["msg"]     = "A sessão de " . $params['inputedData']->$nomeSessoesLogadas .
                    " foi criada com sucesso !";

                session_write_close();

                self::retornarOk(
                    $retorno,
                    $params['htmlEncodeDecodeRet'],
                    $params['tipoRetorno'],
                    $params['identarRetorno']
                );
            }


Are you trying to save something in the session?
You could use the session helper

Why not use tokens like JWT to store information ?

Laravel doesn't use PHPs default sessions, it uses its own session handling
